# Late 80's early 90's British show about teenagers that develop alien powers and sleep/travel in pods

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I have searched about this show and I found it somewhere but I lost it.
The show is about some teenagers that start developing alien powers (one British that attended a private school with red uniforms and blonde/red hair, one was Australian, I believe his name was Adam, and one girl, I believe, black).

They traveled in pods and hid them in the greenhouse and there is also a beach scene, where they go for the pods and can sleep and travel inside of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be the 1990s reboot of *[The Tomorrow People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Tomorrow_People_serials#1990s_series)*, first shown on UK television in 1992, which deals with the adventures of a group of teenagers who develop unusual powers (such as telepathy and being able to teleport). One of the teenagers was indeed called Adam, and was played by an Australian actor called Kristian Schmid. There was a black girl called Lisa (played by Kristian Ariza), and two boys that attended a British school, which as you remember, had a red uniform. One of these boys, "Megabyte" (the blonde one), was not actually British though, but was the son of a general working in the American embassy in London.

Here is a picture of Kevin (left) and Megabyte (right) in their school uniform:

[image: Megabyte stands in his red school uniform with his backpack over his should; he looks over at a smaller boy (Kevin) with dark air in the same uniform who is looking back at him]

I don't remember them traveling in pods, but it has been a long time since I saw it.

Comment: hello thank you very much! it is indeed this series "The tomorrow people" staring Kristian Schmid!

Comment: They never traveled by pods. The pod on the island was the place they went to and was a spaceship buried on the beach taking place of the old subway station in London on the original series.